# Spark Dataframe loosing Partition

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I found this strange problem while reading a spark dataframe. I repartitioned the dataframe into 50k partitions. However, when I read and perform a count action on the dataframe I found that the underlying rdd has only 2143 partitions when I am using spark 2.0.

So I went to the path where I saved the repartitioned data and found that

```
hfs -ls /repartitionedData/ | wc -l
50476
```

So it has created 50k paritions while saving the data.

However with spark 2.0,

```
val d = spark.read.parquet("repartitionedData")
d.rdd.getNumPartitions
res4: Int = 2143
```

But with spark 1.5,

```
val d = spark.read.parquet("repartitionedData")
d.rdd.partitions.length
res4: Int = 50474
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not that you are losing data, Spark only change the number of partitions. [FileSourceStrategy](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileSourceStrategy.scala) combines the parquet files into fewer partitions and also reorders the data.

This is something that changed when Spark got upgraded into version `2.0`. You can find a somewhat related bug report [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20144).

Comment: Thanks for this. No of course I am not loosing data however I was confuse with the change of partition.